# airflow worker not reaching sqs

Tags: celery, amazon-sqs, airflow, worker

I am running the airflow worker service. The service is not able to connect to the sqs

The scheduler is able to reach and write to the queue

Environment:
Amazon Linux
Python 3.54
Airflow 1.10.1
Celery 4.1.1

Proxies are fine; I have implemented this in both python 2.7 and 3.5 same issue

I have set the celery_transport_options for the region
Airflow is configured with celeryExecutor, SQS broker & postgres database for backend

partial log

```
[2018-08-30 15:43:58,779: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: Exception('Request Empty body HTTP 599 Failed to connect to eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection timed out (None)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 207, in start
 self.blueprint.start(self)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
 step.start(parent)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
 return self.obj.start()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 316, in start
 blueprint.start(self)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
 step.start(parent)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 592, in start
 c.loop(*c.loop_args())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 91, in asynloop
 next(loop)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 354, in create_loop
 cb(*cbargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 114, in on_writable
 return self._on_event(fd, _pycurl.CSELECT_OUT)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 124, in _on_event
 self._process_pending_requests()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 132, in _process_pending_requests
 self._process(curl, errno, reason)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 178, in _process
 buffer=buffer, effective_url=effective_url, error=error,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 150, in __call__
 svpending(*ca, **ck)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 143, in __call__
 return self.throw()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 140, in __call__
 retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 100, in _transback
 return callback(ret)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 143, in __call__
 return self.throw()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 140, in __call__
 retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 98, in _transback
 callback.throw()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 96, in _transback
 ret = filter_(*args + (ret,), **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/aws/connection.py", line 233, in _on_list_ready
 raise self._for_status(response, response.read())
Exception: Request Empty body HTTP 599 Failed to connect to eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection timed out (None)
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you added more information about your setup and infrastructure.

Comment: Added environment details

Comment: Can you please share what proxy settings you have done for airflow service to connect to particular SQS queue? I am also working on similar system to setup airflow to talk to SQS, sitting behind a proxy.

Comment: I am importing os and set os.environment[] variables including no_proxy the problem is there is an open issue with kombu package which has a open issue on sqs that it does not get credentials from IAM roles